# System.UnauthorizedAccess Exception: Access to the path c:\\ is denied

Tags: c#, winforms

I am uploading and retrieving documents to and from the DB.Uploading works great
But retrieving is what is causing the error
Here's the code for retrieving

```
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
            int SelectedplantId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["PId"].Value);
            SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
            conn.Open();
            string qry = "select Otherdocuments from Plant where PId = @PId";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(qry, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PId", SelectedpId);

            byte[] buffer = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            conn.Close();

            //string filename = Application.StartupPath + "\\" + sFileName;
           string SaveLocation = "C:" + "\\" + sFileName;
           FileStream fs = null;
           try
           {
               fs = new FileStream(SaveLocation,FileMode.Create);
               fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
           }
           finally
           {
               if (fs != null)
               {
                   ((IDisposable)fs).Dispose();
               }
           }
```

At  fs = new FileStream(SaveLocation,FileMode.Create); is where this exception occurs.

```
Stack Trace
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at RVEST.frmPlant.btnRetrieveDocs_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\D_Drive_Stuff\RVESTV2\RVEST\frmPlant.cs:line 169
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at RVEST.Program.Main() in C:\D_Drive_Stuff\RVESTV2\RVEST\Program.cs:line 26
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
Thank you
```

Sun

Comment: Why would you save documents there? This is probably just UAC interfering. Try saving in a sensible location...

Comment: Yeah, if you're running this on Vista or 7, you probably need your app to be elevated to save to the root of your hard drive. Which makes sense, you know, since you shouldn't save stuff there.

Comment: Is there any other location where I could save it. I dont even have to save. Just opening the file  would be even better and then letting the user save it.

Comment: @ Henk Holterman: winforms, C#

Comment: I don't see where sFilename is set. Are you sure that is a valid filename (Given the error and you comment to @HenkHolterman answer I suspect an empty string)?

Comment: @Steve: Indeed, it is an empty string. Thanks!!

Comment: How can I get the name of the document and the extension. This is so that I can set the string name and the extension

Comment: This could be really problematic if you don't know what type of documents are stored in the db field. Are Word docs, Excel sheets, PDF documents, JPEG images? You need to know this otherwise how do you suppose to show them? For the name (again if you don't have stored the name you could only give a meaningless name) you could simply transform the `SelectedpId` to a string and use as filename

Answer (score 2):

The error message seems obvious, the App does not have permission to write in `C:\` and probably not in `Application.StartupPath` either.

```
 //string filename = Application.StartupPath + "\\" + sFileName;
 //string SaveLocation = "C:" + "\\" + sFileName;
 string SaveLocation = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), sFileName);
```

There are a few other `SpecialFolder`s that might be applicable.

Comment: The problem persists.  I dont even have to save to any folder. Just opening the file would be even better and then letting the user save it